# Can anyone help me identify this plant?

Tags: identification, flowers

I found the plant in my garden. I believe its some kind of weed. I live in Denmark, Europe and we have summer time here at the moment.

Thanks for your time.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previous answer is very close - but I'm willing to bet its actually Cardamine hirsuta, (common name Hairy Bittercress) a common weed in Europe in gardens and other places, and one which I  spend a great deal of time weeding out. The flowers on C. pratensis are more attractive and different than the weedy, white ones C. hirsuta produces.

http://www.pfaf.org/user/plant.aspx?LatinName=Cardamine+hirsuta

Comment: I googled " Cardamine hirsuta" and found pictures that matches the plant i found. Thank you for identifying it! I have it all over my garden at the moment. I attached a new picture. Zoom in a great deal and you can see the jungle of Cardamine hirsutas.

Comment: You are right, I had overlooked the "fuzz" on the leaves.

Comment: @Stephie - I know this weed really well without checking hairiness or otherwise - sick to death of the blasted thing - pity it isn't the one you've named, I'd be pleased to see that one!

Comment: I agree. The one Stephie mentioned looks beautiful. I bet it has a nice scent too.